# Laravel filter on a relation using scopes

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, belongs-to

I have the following models:

`Order` and `OrderState`.

In the `Order` model I have defined relationship:

```
    public function fullState() : ?BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderState::class, 'order_state_id', 'id');
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to get all Orders that have a certain OrderState. I have created scope methods in my `Order` class

```
    public function scopeNotCancelled(Builder $query) : Builder
        return $query->with('fullState')->whereHas('fullState', function ($q) {
            $q->notCancelled();
        });
    }

    public function scopeNotPostponed(Builder $query) : Builder
        return $query->with('fullState')->whereHas('fullState', function ($q) {
            $q->notPostponed();
        }]);
    }
```

And in my `OrderState` class I have following method with scopes:

```
    public function scopeNotCancelled(Builder $query) : Builder
    {
        return $query->where('key', '<>', self::CANCELLED);
    }

    public function scopeNotPostponed(Builder $query) : Builder
    {
        return $query->where('key', '<>', self::POSTPONED);
    }
```

My query looks like this:

```
$salesOrders = SalesOrder::notCancelled()
            ->notPostponed()
            ->get()
```

What am I doing wrong here, can anybody see? This is the error that I am seeing.

```
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Order.order_state_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Order` where exists (select * from `OrderState` where `Order`.`order_state_id` = `OrderState`.`id` and `key` <> CANCELLED) and exists (select * from `OrderState` where `Order`.`order_state_id` = `OrderState`.`id` and `key` <> POSTPONED) and `order_state_id` <> 0)
```

Comment: If you followed Laravel naming convention, your table name should be `Orders` not `Order`. Maybe that's why you have an "unknown column" error.

Comment: Another tip, do not do `?BelongsTo`, as a relation (`fullState` for example) will **ALWAYS** return `BelongsTo`, it will never be `null`. What it can be `null` is the data for that relation, hence `$model->fullState` can be `null` but `$model->fullState()` will never be `null`.